# Session Management in Castle Active Record

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

How do I manage session if I am using Castle Active Record over nHibernate. Basically I can manage the life cycle of ISession on my own if I am using nHibernate directly. But when I am using Castle AR it does not give me a way to manage the life cycle of the session. I want to use single Session per thread.

---

*I am using Castle AR in a WCF service and would like to use Session per WCF Request.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ISession, in Castle ActiveRecord you want SessionScope:

```
using(new SessionScope())
{
  ; // do work here
}
```

If you need access to the ISession inside the SessionScope for some reason, you can do this:

```
ISession dbSession = Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordMediator
      .GetSessionFactoryHolder().CreateSession(
          typeof(Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase));
```

More documentation is here:

http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/scopes.html#sess_scope

and here:

http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/scopes.html

Comment: Doesn't work, gives a object ref not set to an instance of an object error when you try to get the dbSession.

Comment: Do you know if calling `.CreateSession()` on the session factory holder will create a current scope?  When I try it, SessionScope.Current is null, thus lazy loading fails.  It must be possible to initialize a current session scope since `SessionScopeWebModule` does it.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  You just have to new up a `SessionScope` and it registered it within the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working in a web app.  Is that not the case?

There are a couple of ways to do it - [Castle AR documentation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/web.html)

The simplest way is to the use SessionScopeWebModule to give a session per request.

Comment: I am working in web app but web apps delegates call to a WCF service where Castle AR is used. I would like to use Session per WCF Request?