# Class work outside of session

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

As you see in the following code, I close session in `Save` method. I guess thats why `AddUserSettings` doesn't work. What is the best practise to make this work? Is closing session in `Save` method bad idea? At `UserSettings` save there is no user in DB yet so is that creates the problem? How do I handle that out of session?

**User**

```
public class User : BaseClass<User>
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

public virtual void AddUserSettings(UserSettings us)
{
    us.User = this;
    UserSettings = us;
}
```

**UserSettings**

```
public class UserSettings : BaseClass<UserSettings>
{
    public virtual int UserSettingsId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual string FacebookId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FacebookToken { get; set; }
}
```

**Save Method**

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
     using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
          session.SaveOrUpdate(x);

          transaction.Commit();
     }
}
```

**Code**

```
user = new Entity.User();
us = new Entity.UserSettings();

us.FacebookId = "foo";
us.FacebookToken = "foo";
user.AddUserSettings(us);
us.Save();

user.UserName = "foo";
user.FirstName = "foo";
user.LastName = "foo";
user.Email= "foo";

user.Save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem;

First I need to create main object and save then I can add sub class without problem.

```
user = new Entity.User();
user.UserName = "foo";
user.FirstName = "foo";
user.LastName = "foo";
user.Email= "foo";
user.Save();

us = new Entity.UserSettings();
us.FacebookId = "foo";
us.FacebookToken = "foo";
user.AddUserSettings(us);
us.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

A session should be used per business operation so micro managing it in every save method is not a good idea:

- more roundtrips since NHibernate can not batch multiple inserts/updates together
- impossible to define a transaction over more than one entity !!!
- horrible performance because the database must create a transaction for each insert/update (try inserting 10k users with your "framework" and then with one session and transaction)
- changetracking must be handled implicitly (calling a method which may alter an entity and the session will update only if it has changed vs in your case it will always update all fields because it doesn't know if/what changed)
- unit testing is harder because there is always one global NHibernateHelper(sessionfactory)
- you have to create/save entities in your buisiness logic in the right order to avoid the problems stated in the question because the session that would do it for you is closed

See [Caslte.ActiveRecord example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223664/671619) for how to handle sessions when using the ActiveRecord pattern. Essentially the session is shared per context to have meaningfull transaction boundaries and performance gains.

Or you switch to using the session outside of the entities so you have more options and features of NHibernate to your disposal.